# Problems giving Firebase SDK local login persistence with react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, authentication

I've tried all the tools given in the documentation and in stack overflow and am confused about how to create login persistence.

`setPersistence(auth, localPersistence);`

does not work when I implement it, as well as some other variations of this. Some sources say that I need to implement redux while some say that firebase should have this as a default and all I need is to implement something like

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log('user is logged');
      }
});
```

Here is my code right now for authentication, please let me know how to set local persistence.

Firebase phone auth functions:
'''
const sendVerification = () => {
const phoneProvider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
phoneProvider
.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumberWithCode, recaptchaVerifier.current)
.then(setVerificationId);
setConfirming(!confirming);
setCode('');
};

```
const confirmCode = () => {
    const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId,
        code
    );
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
    .then(() => {
        setCode('');
        checkIfPhoneExists(phoneNumberWithCode).then((userExists) => {
            if (userExists) {
                navigation.navigate('Threads');
            } else {
                navigation.navigate('EnterInfo');
            }
        })
        createAccountIfNotUser(phoneNumberWithCode);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Firebase app and auth initialization:

```
export const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);
auth.languageCode = 'it';
setPersistence(auth, localPersistence);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve persistance with Firebase, you can install [@react-native-async-storage/async-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage) and use it with the firebase app.

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { initializeAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth/react-native";

const app = initializeApp({ ... });

initializeAuth(app, {
   persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
});
```

Comment: I implemented this solution and the app still works but does not yet have local authentication persistence.  Does doing it as I do below make it not work for some reason or do you know any possible reason this isn't working?                                                                     
export const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
});

Comment: I cant import: import { getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth/react-native"; as it does not find it.